# why mongoose populate causes 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error in nextjS server action?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, next.js13

I return a mongoose find query in a nextjs (version 13.5) server action and encounter 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. I think the main cause of the problem is mongoose populate method because when I remove it, the error doesn't display anymore  :

```
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Call Stack
String.replace
<anonymous>
_e
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:447398)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:448056)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:449122)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:449122)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:449122)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:449122)
Re
file:///C:/Users/hossein/homebnb/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (1:449122)
```

my server action:

```
import { Types } from "mongoose";
import Reservation from "@/models/Reservation";

interface IParams {
  listingId?: string;
  userId?: string;
  authorId?: string;
}

export default async function getReservations(params: IParams) {
  const { listingId, userId, authorId } = params;

  const query: any = {};

  if (listingId) {
    query.listingId = new Types.ObjectId(listingId);
  }

  if (userId) {
    query.userId = userId;
  }

  if (authorId) {
    query.listing = { userId: authorId };
  }

  console.log("QUERY: " + JSON.stringify(query));
  try {
    const reservations = await Reservation.find(query)
      .populate({ path: "userId", select: "name" })

      .then((p) => {
        return p;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    console.log("REsSSSSS" + reservations);

    return reservations;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `.then((p) => { return p; })` accomplishes?

Comment: @Wyck it returns the query found (promise response) that will be assigned to 'reservations ' then.

Comment: It is actually a "no-op".  The entire clause can be omitted.  `foo.then(p => p).catch(bar)` can just be written `foo.catch(bar)`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I deleted the redundant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by adding .lean() method to the end of mongoose query like this:

```
const reservations = await Reservation.find(query).populate({ path: "userId", select: "name" }).lean();
```

as mongoose documents says:

> The lean option tells Mongoose to skip hydrating the result documents. This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining how this solves the problem.

Comment: @Wyck thanks for your advice. I added the mongoose document explanation about lean method

Comment: Do you have a clear understanding now of why the stack was exceeded in the case where you do not use `.lean()`?

Comment: @Wyck actually not a clear understanding but somehow i know what's the problem. I would appreciate If you explain it completely

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update your `try and catch` logic and it will work.

```
try {    
    const reservations = await Reservation.find(query)
    .populate({ path: "userId", select: "name" })

    if (!reservations) {
       throw new Error("No reservations found.");
    }

    console.log("RESERVATIONS: " + JSON.stringify(reservations));
    
    return reservations; 
} catch (error: any) {    
    throw new Error(error);    
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but it didn't work